# Using FluentAssertions to compare two collections of dictionaries that are containing different types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

From our database, we querying sets of records that are put in a collection of dynamic objects of type `ExpandoObject` that implements `IDictionary<string, object>` on the fields. These are the actual values.

From our SpecFlow BDD tests we get a collection of TableRows that implements `IDictionary<string, string>`. These are our expected values.

With FluentAssertions we'd like to test on equivalency on the whole collection with `actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected)`. Unfortunately, this won't work, because of the mismatch in types when the actual values are not of type `string`.

We could use `actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithAutoConversion())`, but this will make the whole actual set a collection of `IDictionary<string, string>` which is not useful for comparing dates.

I assembled a testcase that will show the same issue:

```
var expected = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
expected.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Name", "Moon Inc."},
    {"Number", "42"},
    {"Date", "2018-12-31"}
});

var actual = new List<ExpandoObject>();
dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
eo.Name = "Moon Inc.";
eo.Number = 42;
eo.Date = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);

actual.Add(eo);

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options);
/* 
    This throws:
    NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: 
    Expected item[0][Number] to be System.String, but found System.Int32.
    Expected item[0][Date] to be System.String, but found System.DateTime.
*/

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithAutoConversion());
/*
    This throws:
    NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: 
    Expected item[0][Date] to be "2018-12-31" with a length of 10, 
    but "31-12-2018 0:00:00" has a length of 18.
/*
```

I tried to make the receiving type dynamic in a using method like:

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options
    .Using<dynamic>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()
    .Using<dynamic>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<int>());

/* 
    NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: 
    Expected item[0][Number] to be System.String, but found System.Int32.
    Expected item[0][Date] to be System.String, but found System.DateTime.
*/
```

Parsing both sides to a `DateTime` and using autoconversion does also not work because the `actual` type is not seen as a `DateTime` but as `string`:

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options
    .Using<dynamic>(
        ctx =>
            DateTime.ParseExact(ctx.Subject, "yyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            .Should().Be(DateTime.ParseExact(ctx.Expectation, "yyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    .WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()
    .WithAutoConversion());

/*
    NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: 
    Expected item[0][Date] to be "2018-12-31" with a length of 10, 
    but "31-12-2018 0:00:00" has a length of 18.
*/
```

Is there any way with FluentAssertions to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing else helps, you can implement custom `IEquivalencyStep` like this:

```
class WeakDateEquivalencyStep : IEquivalencyStep {
    public bool CanHandle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) {
        if (context.IsRoot)
            return false;
        // handles situations when subject is date
        // but expectation is string
        return context.Subject is DateTime && context.Expectation is string;
    }

    public bool Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) {
        DateTime exp;
        // we know that expection is string here
        if (!DateTime.TryParse((string) context.Expectation, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out exp)) {
            // do something, your spec is invalid
            throw new Exception($"Value {context.Expectation} does not represent valid date time");
        }

        context.Subject.Should().Be(exp, context.Because, context.BecauseArgs);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => 
   options.Using(new WeakDateEquivalencyStep()).WithAutoConversion());
```

Comment: This works perfect for my case and with this knowledge, I can extend it for other types too. Thank you very much!